Double cosets $N\backslash \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q})/N$.
Let $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{F}_{q}$ (though, as I understand this is not crucial for my question). Let $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F})$ be a general linear group of $2\times 2$ matrices. I'm interested in the classification of double cosets of $N\backslash \mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{q})/N$. Here
\begin{equation}
N = \left\{\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\ \middle| \ x\in\mathbb{F} \right\}
\end{equation}
are unipotent upper triangular matrices.
As I understand we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&y\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}*&*\\c&*\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
meaning that we can see that $B$ the subgroup of upper-triangular matrices is the disjoint union of cosets of form
\begin{equation}
N\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}&0\\0&a_{2}\end{pmatrix}N
\end{equation}
it is easy to check that any matrix
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}a_{1}&z\\0&a_{2}\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
can be obtained from $\mathrm{diag}(a_{1},a_{2})$ by action of $N$ from left and right and that it cannot be obtained from any other matrix in this way.
The other double cosets have to be located in $B\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}B = N\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}B $ as  I understand the Bruhat decomposition. However I'm not sure, how they look exactly. What are the natural representatives? Are they $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\mathrm{diag}(a_{1},a_{2})$ and if yes, what is the easy way to see this?
Is it true that for $\mathrm{GL}_{n}$ the representatives are of the form $w\mathrm{diag}(a_{1},\dots,a_{n})$ with $w\in W$ (Weyl group)?

I think, i see, why are they $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\mathrm{diag}(a_{1},a_{2})$. It is rather easy to check that if a matrix
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_1&0\\0&a_2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&y\\0&1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}a_1 x&a_1 xy + a_{2}\\a_1&a_1 y\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
is obtained from a matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\mathrm{diag}(a_{1}',a_{2}')$, then necessarily $a_{1}' = a_1$ and  $a_{2}' = a_{2}$.
